# Instantiating multiple templates

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a class called `Tuple<T, SIZE>` and I want, let's say, 20 different float templates instantiated when compiling the library (so that the user does not encounter linking errors):

```
template Tuple<float, 1>;
template Tuple<float, 2>;
...
template Tuple<float, 20>;
```

Is there any way to recursively perform the above? And maybe allow it to be flexible so that I can put it any number I would like and it instantiates the classes for me?

**EDIT:** What I have tried so far (does not seem to work):

```
template <typename T, unsigned int MAX_RANGE>
class AllTuples
{
  Tuple<T, MAX_RANGE> y;
  AllTuples<T, MAX_RANGE - 1> x;
};

template <typename T>
class AllTuples<T, 1>
{
  Tuple<T, 1> x;
};
AllTuples<float, 10>;
```

Comment: The `AllTuples::x` should also be an `AllTuples`, not a `Tuple`.

Comment: @Xeo: Thanks for pointing that out, fixed (although still does not fix the original problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry you are out of luck. Unless you use a preprocessor metaprogramming library (boost.pp), there is no way to automate that. Not with template metaprogramming.

What you have produced there are *implicit instantiations* of `Tuple<float, N>`. But implicit instantiations have two important differences to explicit instantiations

1. They won't instantiate all member definitions (only those that are immediately needed are instantiated). Other definitions are only instantiated when they are used.
2. The implicit instantiation of used member definitions cannot be used as a definition source for other translation units.

For the latter, since I'm not aware of the reason for that, I will just quote the spec.

> A non-exported template must be defined in every translation unit in which it is implicitly instantiated (14.7.1), unless the corresponding specialization is explicitly instantiated (14.7.2) in some translation unit; no diagnostic is required.

That may have to do with linker complications, because implicit instantiations for the same template can occur multiple times in multiple translation units, so they need special handling. Explicit instantiations and non-inline functions can't.

Comment: `"That may have to do with linker complications, because implicit instantiations for the same template can occur multiple times in multiple translation units, so they need special handling. Explicit instantiations and non-inline functions can't."` Why is that different than typing `template Tuple<float, 3>` in `Tuple.cpp` which can then be used in multiple translation units without linking errors? Please excuse my lack of knowledge as I am relatively new to templates.

Comment: @Samaursa if you type `template Tuple<float 3>;` in `Tuple.cpp` and `List.cpp`, then your program is ill-formed (without a diagnostic required). An explicit instantiation can only appear once for a given class. As far as I understand, explicitly instantiated functions have strong linkage on GCC, so such an ill-formed program will produce a linker error, because two strong-linkage symbols cannot be linked together. Implicitly instantiated functions have weak linkage, meaning that the compiler will discard all but one version of them.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your comment. I am not typing it in `List.cpp`...? What I am currently doing is what is suggested here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13 . The problem as stated in the question is that I have a lot of `template Tuple<float, N>` for maximum range I want to support, and I want to avoid typing all of them if possible.

Comment: I don't know why and where it will cause problems if you try to implicitly instantiate the template and then use it as a definition source. My understanding has been that the model GCC uses can cope with this. If you want to know, I suggest you make a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some template magic to force that instantiation:

```
namespace {
    template <unsigned N>
    struct Instantiator {
        void instantiate_members(const Tuple<float,N>& tuple, Instantiator<N-1>) {
            // use **all** member functions here
            // so that they get instantiated
        }

    template <>
    struct Instantiator<0> {}
}
```

And then instantiate this template:

```
template class Instantiator<20>;
```

Unfortunately this is not good in terms of maintenance, because you need to keep the instantiate_members function up to date. And you need to make sure *all* members are called, including all the various overloads.

Comment: +1 Nice, though I still disagree with doing this in the first place

Comment: This will instantiate the class, but not the member methods

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: That is indeed what seems to be the case and why it is not working for me.

Comment: @David: good point. I made an edit in an (foolish?) attempt to work around that limitation.

Comment: @David: the member will be instantiated by the explicit instantiation of `Instantiator`. It doesn't call anything at runtime, unless you decide to use the `Instantiator` class in your code. And I agree that using the preprocessor is probably a better idea.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: Oh, you are right, I missed that. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to avoid linkage errors with templates is to put the template definitions in every TU where you use them. Usually a header file is best suited for this purpose. Using explicit instantiation like this is at best semi-effective, and at worst just damned confusing.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately I have the requirement imposed on me that I cannot release the source code :(

Comment: @Samarusa: A tiny bit of code generation might work here, I think a three-line bash script inside your makefile would generate a header file containing the first block of code, for any number you choose.  But you will definitely have portability problems.